# how to declare a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I declare a database as when I try the following:

```
declare @Database1 [$(Database1)]
```

It states 'Column, parameter, or variable #8: Cannot find data type Database1'.

UPDATE:

So what I am trying to do is create a variable so that it refers to a database, and then I can include that variable in an OUTPUT statement. I'm using visual studio where by I'm using a reference to call the database, but want that reference to be set as a variable:

At the moment I have:

```
declare @Database1 [$(Database1)]

...

OUTPUT ''+@Database1+'.dbo.Package' 'TableName', 'PackageID', inserted.PackageId, 
        Core.updXMLFragment ('StatusID', inserted.StatusID, Deleted.StatusID)
        INTO @OutputList
```

Like I said I get an error when I try the above. I know `[$(Database1)]` is a legit reference to a database, just need to know how to include this into an OUTPUT statement so that when I move it SSMS, it displays it as [Database1] and not an error.

The reason for `[$(Database1)]` is so that if we ever change the database name, we don't have to change it in our code as we are using this reference to call on the database rather than the database name itself.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `Dynamic SQL`

```
DECLARE @Database SYSNAME = 'master'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
USE ' + QUOTENAME(@Database) + '

SELECT DB_NAME()
'

--PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Just a side-note, I prefer using `QUOTENAME` to quote properly rather than manually slapping rectangular brackets on yourself.

Comment: I'm thinking of adding the variable to an output variable: e.g OUTPUT ''+@Database1+'dbo....', will this method work in this situation if I use dynamic sql at start like you mentioned?

Comment: @BruceyBandit please provide a small sample for your situation

Comment: @Devart I've provided a sample in my question as an update

Comment: @Devart, just found out that it is not the declare that seems to be the issue, it is actually the +@Database1+ that is the issue. If I did not set it to a variable and just placed the usual database statement in an ouput statement as OUTPUT ''+[Database1]+'.dbo....', it gives me an error as well

Answer (score 1):

One can use [sqlcmd Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) to declare the same.

```
:setvar dbname "TEST" 

CREATE DATABASE $(dbname)
GO
ALTER DATABASE $(dbname) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
GO
ALTER DATABASE $(dbname) SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
```

Comment: I want to declare the database as a variable so that it can be used with an OUTPUT command. Can your answer be modified to fit this?